# Possible to set window to full size in Yosemite when pressing green button?

Tags: macos

In Yosemite when I press a window's green 'fullsize' button, it will be full size, but somehow differently from earlier way, I can not use change between windows shortcut, because window will claim the whole screen. Any idea how to use it earlier?

Answer (score 4):

To have the previous behaviour use Option+Click.

Actually, pressing Option+Click on different things opens a whole lot of new possibilities.

Comment: option + click will stretch it but not use the whole screen, do you know why?

Comment: This is the way OS X works. In Windows "maximize" fills the whole screen. In OS X it is theoretically making window as large as possible to wrap the content, which means no unused space is covered by window. In practice it usually means what expected, but often the behaviour is overriden by the app (such as iTunes) and is hardly unpredictable.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a third party app and define a key combination.

I personally use [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/) (I am not affiliated with it) and defined <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

[image]

Or you can hover with the mouse on the green button and after a short delay choose the windows layout:

[image]

There are other tools ([DoublePane](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/doublepane/id409737246?mt=12), [divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/) or [Slate](https://github.com/jigish/slate)) but I never tried them.